# How to refactor function overloads with different arity without using overloads?

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-typings

I have a typescript function declaration with different arity:

```js
function f(): void;
function f(code: 0): void;
function f(code: 1, msg: string): void;
function f(code: 0 | 1 = 0, msg?: string): void { /* omit implementation */ }
```

Thus it can be invoked as:

```js
f() // ok
f(0) // ok
f(1, "error message") // ok
f(0, "message") // type error
f(1) // type error
```

My question is how can I refactor this function declaration without using function overload?
(For example, with union types, conditional types, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can type arguments combinations with union types:

```
function f(...args: [] | [0] | [1, string]): void { /* omit implementation */ }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=80#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXIgNoC6iAPqQAwXUkCMANIvlNjGLmQJTEA3ODAAmiAN6IA9ACpEcALYwoiGAoAOAGwCmC7WCiZYCRDKmIAvgCgbqXtPNwA1ldQ17Uxy9QtEAIm1sbDhsRD18fExcbT8PL1cUGlY-cMjo2IdEKABPdW1EQODsBMY4rNz8wpCgA)

* Version with overloads still looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
type Message = {code: 0 } | {code: 1, messageText?: string};

const useMessage = (message?: Message) => {};

const usedMessage_0 = useMessage();
const usedMessage_1 = useMessage({code: 0});
const usedMessage_2 = useMessage({code: 1});

const usedMessage_3 = useMessage({code: 0, messageText: 'something'}); // type error
const usedMessage_4 = useMessage({code: 1, messageText: 'something'});
```